# Unable to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 on newly assembled PC via burned CD

Tags: 12.04, server, system-installation, cd

I just assembled a new PC/server for use as a small server in a small business. Ubuntu Server 12.04 was recommended because 13 is not as well supported in community.

How to install Ubuntu Server on a newly assembled empty server?

The CD that I burned (with the newly downloaded 12.04 on it) does not boot from my CD drive.  It's either not bootable or not recognized by BIOS.

Comment: did you burn the disc .iso file to a disc or did you create a disc from the .iso file? Look on the disc on another computer. If it has only one file then you've burnt it wrong and need to burn the contents of the iso image to the disc, not just copy the single file.

Comment: Great spot!!.. I did not even notice even after burning 2 cd's becuase i suspected he first to be corrupt. I looked now and it was single file on disc.. will reburn correct and retry install. If it works I will return to thank.

Comment: Thanx allot!! your advice worked. currently installing.

thanx for offering your time to help noobs like me. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

When you download Ubuntu, you download a .iso file which is an *image* of the installation disc. The **contents** of this .iso file need to be burnt to a CD to make it bootable, not just the .iso file.