# How to solve Syslinux 4.07 EDD Load error Boot error

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I had the blue screen, downloaded Ubuntu using universal USB...  In a new USB, formatted and when I inserted it in my laptop I got the error in the title of my post. Any help there?

Answer (score 0):

Try with dd command.

Download ubuntu.iso file:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Plug the usbstick

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Suppose that the usbstick is /dev/sdb1, continue running:

```
umount /dev/sdb1
dd if=/home/user/Downloads/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M && sync
```

## Note:

of= drive (/dev/sdb) not partition (/dev/sdb1), all data are erased

Comment: `dd` is a powerful, but dangerous tool, when used in this way. Many people have overwritten valuable data because they have written to the wrong device. Cloning tools with a final checkpoint help avoiding this problem, https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/929586#929586