# Dual booting Ubuntu alongside windows 10.0

Tags: system-installation

I've tried like many times to install ubuntu to run alongside windows 10 but i always fail, no option for booting from CD/DVD in the computer. What am I gonna do to get this working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the universal way to write an Ubuntu ISO image on a USB stick?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-universal-way-to-write-an-ubuntu-iso-image-on-a-usb-stick) and possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 10 with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

try making a bootable usb using unetbootin or yumi.
And while installing ubuntu select partition manually. Then do not delete your windows partition just select the unallocated space and create a new "/" root patition from the remaining space and install you ubuntu.