# Dell inspiron 3552 won't boot from a live usb

Tags: boot, usb, dell

I am trying to reinstall my laptop and want to remove the OEM OS present. I have turned off secure boot and fast boot in the BIOS menu. When I plug in my live usb I get to the selection screen and choose Ubuntu. After that the screen goes blank and it does not boot. Legacy mode does not work. Are there any possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried booting it in legacy mode?

Comment: Yes. It still does not work.

Comment: Are you able to enter into BIOS menu?

Comment: Enter bios and change boot order... make the USB first, and be sure the USB is in a good shape, retry it and let us know the outcome..

Comment: I wrote a general all case answer for solving this type of problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/674454#674454. Comment if it doesn't work, so we can continue by going into more detail about specifics.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried all of the solutions posted here and nothing has worked out. I have contacted the manufacturer and will be sending the machine back for service. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you know what video card it has built-in?