# Installing Ubuntu with no OS

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive

I am going to be using Ubuntu for the first time. How do I install it to hp 3130 cpu? My unit has no OS so I don't really know how to get around it. I was just wondering what if USB stick/drive is not yet recognized, what do I do?

Comment: Did you try it? Until now I never had a PC that didn't recognize USB drives..just make sure It is installed with the correct bootloader (UEFI vs BIOS) anyway sometimes there comes an Error during installation from USB about "missing CD" ore something similar. In this case just disconnect the USB and plug it to the same port again than it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu *is an* operating system, so it has no requirements on other OSes being installed before. In fact, it is *easier* to install Ubuntu as the first OS than to add it beside a current one (although this is more common). Since you do not have any previous OS to take care of, you *cannot break anything* during the installation (there is simply nothing to break), so do not worry and give it a try!

There are known situations when USB drive is not recognized.

1. *BIOS cannot work with USB drives directly.* This most likely won’t happen to a computer made after, let’s say, 2005.
2. *The drive is not bootable.* You can avoid this by using a tool like [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/). See [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso) for a detailed guide.