# Wifi drops after ~ 5 minutes with RTL8821AE

Tags: wireless

My wifi connection doesnt work properly; it stays connected only for around 5 minutes after I turn on the PC. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I've tried

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

which makes no difference

Same with

```
killall nm-applet && nm-applet &
```

After that I tried

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

where I insert this string

```
SUSPEND_MODULES = "drivername logicalchipname"
```

But since I don't have permission to modify that file I tried to use `chmod` on it, which led to [A problem that was solved](https://askubuntu.com/q/939477/717319) but left me still in the same situation.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1b9a:2482]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
 Kernel modules: rtl8821ae

0: hci0: Bluetooth  Soft blocked: yes   Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN   Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no
```

What do you suggest I do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/939477/ubuntu-16-04-lts-lost-administrator-rights-bash-etc-profile-permission-denied#comment1490504_939477

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Edited and output added

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Same problem as [Wireless disconnect issues Ubuntu 16.04 with RTL8821ae](//askubuntu.com/q/797213) but I don't think this question has a working answer

Comment: So do you think Is an hardware problem?? In the case i still have assiciration

Comment: Sorry rinzwind i didnt see your post, i've already tried what you said and it doesnt work

Comment: This seems a method: https://gauravssnl.wordpress.com/2017/06/18/how-to-fix-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-network-adapter-low-wi-fi-signal-issue-on-ubuntulinux-os/  Change the "rtl8723be" for your "rtl8821ae". it also describes the same problems you list.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind finally i solved this issue!! Otherwise i've should reinstall again Ubuntu and It Will be the third time... Thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**if wifi quits working again execute the commands given again (you must do this everytime there is a kernel update)**

Thanks to @Rinzwind I've found a way to solve the problem, just follow [this guide](https://gauravssnl.wordpress.com/2017/06/18/how-to-fix-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-network-adapter-low-wi-fi-signal-issue-on-ubuntulinux-os/):

> 1. Download `rtlwifi_new` from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) and extract it to
>      Desktop (or to your desired folder).
> 2. Open Terminal and change your directory to the folder where you extracted rtlwifi_new zip file (here , Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master)  by
>      using the `cd` command, eg
>
>    ```
>    cd Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master
>    ```
> 3. Now, run these commands in Terminal:
>
>    ```
>    make clean 
>    make 
>    sudo make install
>    ```
> 4. If everything is alright, you will see the message `Install rtlwifi SUCCESS`. It means that rtlwifi has beeen installed successfully.
> 5. Now, run this command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo modprobe rtl8723be
>    ```
> 6. Amd run this command:
>
>    ```
>    echo “options rtl8723be ant_sel=2” | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
>    ```

Then reboot and choose your wifi network to connect.

Comment: Did you have to change "rtl8723be" for your "rtl8821ae?

Comment: Yes, in the original link posted by @Rinzwind  in the comments there is a list of which "rtl.." are compatible with the solution