# Wifi drops after ~ 5 minutes with RTL8821AE ... again

Tags: wireless

My wifi connection doesnt work properly; it stays connected only for around 5 minutes after I turn on the PC. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Here you can find all the actions that i've tried and a temporary solution that worked for a week:
[Wifi drops after ~ 5 minutes with RTL8821AE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939758/wifi-drops-after-5-minutes-with-rtl8821ae)

The strange thing is that in the last 4 days I never turned off my notebook; I only suspended it when I was going to sleep. Last night I turned it off and this morning the wifi issue came back...

Do you think that there are other possible solutions?

Comment: Haver you installed the drivers mentioned in the linked question? If so, you need to repeat the process whenever there's a kernel update.

Comment: If you mean rtlfwifi_new and the commands sudo make, make clean, male install, modprobe rtl8821ae yes I've done them all when i was adjusting the issue

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBay It seems that you were right, to install the drivers  should i run a command like sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new ??

Comment: No, you should make clean and follow the same instructions. APT installs software from repositories, already packaged for Debian/Ubuntu. This drivers needs compiling.

Comment: Thanks so anytime there is a kernel update i must execute those commands to compile the drivers

Comment: @ZenoRaiser until such a time when someone packages it or makes a `akmod` or similar, yes

Answer (score 1):

Solution: everytime there is a kernel update execute the commands of the given link in the question

Comment: Why not just add it to dkms?  Should be able to `sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new` or `sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new-master` depending on what the directory is named

Comment: I don't know if It would work and i can't try It now because the wifi works, the next time it drops i Will try it. So with that command i should never again repeat the sequence of the solution?

Comment: Dkms will build the module for a new kernel when the kernel is being installed.  When you reboot into the new kernel the module is already there.  I think Pilot6 added the commit that gave rtlwifi-new dkms support

Comment: @Jeremy31 that's a worthy answer in my opinion

Comment: @Jeremy31 i did what you said now just before a new update i've 1- executed your commands 2-update the system 3-reboot and it didnt work so i had ti execute again all the procedure. Also It displayed on the screen something like "there is an error with the software rtlwifi_new-master is an external package please remove It" (i've added the module in usr/src)