# Wifi issue after running sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new-master

Tags: wireless, dkms

I've already solved my initial wifi problem here: [Wifi drops after ~ 5 minutes with RTL8821AE | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939758/wifi-drops-after-5-minutes-with-rtl8821ae) but I've tried to optimize it (because anytime there was a kernel update I have to execute all the commands of the solution again) and I've messed up something.

To solve the kernel update problem I tried

```
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new-master
```

just before an update. I ran the command in the Desktop folder but I got this output:

```
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-rtlwifi_new-master does not exist.
```

So I thought that I should have run the given command while in `/usr/src/` folder, so I did so, but after doing that my wifi problem got worse and now every time I reboot the PC I need to execute the whole solution again, whereas before this process was necessary only after a kernel update.

Also, on the main screen I see something like

```
there is an error! rtlwifi_new-master is an external package. Please remove it
```

In summary:

1. I got a notification of a system update
2. I executed `sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new-master` in src folder
3. I didn't reboot
4. I executed the update
5. I rebooted
6. Worse problem than before

I thought of running

```
rm -R  rtlwifi-new-0.10
```

in the /src folder but I don't have the permission and I've already messed up with that one time. You can see it here:

[Ubuntu 16.04 lts lost administrator rights bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939477/ubuntu-16-04-lts-lost-administrator-rights-bash-etc-profile-permission-denied)

Suggestions??

Comment: What is the result for `ls | grep rtlwifi`  You likely have it in your /home

Comment: I tried the command in Desktop, home and / folders and i've got nothing as a result. I tried ls | grep rtlwifi in /usr/src and i've got this:                                   `rtlwifi-new-0.10
rtlwifi-new-0.6 `                                                                                                                                     Both of the 2 lines have a red color(guess for the permissions)

Comment: Any result from `ls  /var/lib/dkms | grep rtlwifi`  Were you compiling the new driver every time in /usr/src/ before?

Comment: no i was compiling it every time from here:  `/home/zenoraiser/Scrivania/RisoluzioneProbPC/Mega-svarione-wifi-risolto/rtlwifi_new-master` which are some folders that i've created in desktop to track the pc issues that i've solved. With last command requested i've got this output: rtlwifi-new (rtlwifi again red)

Answer (score 0):

First, in `terminal`, do a `man dkms` to read/learn about dkms.

Second, assure that any dkms kernel module doesn't already exist in the system, or is older that the source that you're working with.

To install a dkms module, you copy the source code to /usr/src with a folder name in the **format of module-version** (ie:rtlwifi-0.10). *(Adjust the following examples as necessary).*

```
sudo cp -r rtlwifi-new-0.10 /usr/src/rtlwifi-0.10
```

Then you issue a series of dkms commands like so:

```
dkms status # to show the current dkms status
```

Due to your previous attempts, you may have to clean up dkms first, with:

```
dkms remove module/version -k "$(uname -r)/$(uname -p)"
```

Then you can start fresh:

```
sudo dkms add rtlwifi/0.10 -k "$(uname -r)/$(uname -p)"

sudo dkms build rtlwifi/0.10 -k "$(uname -r)/$(uname -p)"

sudo dkms install rtlwifi/0.10 -k "$(uname -r)/$(uname -p)"

dkms status # to show the final dkms status
```