# Help Needed: Facing Issues in ISO to bootable USB conversion

Tags: live-usb, iso

When I try to create bootable USB stick for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, after conversion one or many of the following happen

1. No files are seen in the flash drive.
2. I get 'the file is corrupt' message.
3. The flash drive space remains occupied
4. Flash drive isn't recognized by the computer

I have tried using different, completely new, undamaged flash drives. Upon using Rufus I get a message, "Access denied."

Please guide me resolve this issue.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by convert? You should be able to write a iso image to a usb drive without any problems.

Comment: Also, are you trying to write the usb drive from a windows or a Linux machine?

Comment: Mint is off topic here.

Comment: Which ISO files do you want to boot from a USB drive specifically? The procedure may vary depending on the ISO layout and bootloader type among others.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I couldn't make USB stick. So tried Linux Mint. Same issue faced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](/q/287064/175814)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most linux iso files are hybrid iso files. It means that they can be cloned to a USB pendrive and the USB pendrive will be a bootable drive (live drive or install drive).

- In current versions of Ubuntu you can use **Disks** alias **`gnome-disks`**,
- in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions you can also use the **Startup Disk Creator** to clone from the iso file to a USB pendrive,
- You can install **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)** in most current linux distros,

to clone from the iso file to a USB pendrive.

- In Windows you can use

  - **[Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)** to clone or
  - **[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)** to extract

from the iso file to a USB pendrive. The cloning process is straight-forward and therefore very reliable.

But Rufus has a good reputation, so I don't know why it was failing for you. Please check with `md5sum` that the iso file was downloaded correctly. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

---

The following links (and links from them) add more tips how create a USB boot drive

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

[Download the iso file and check that it was downloaded correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/929586#929586)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer especially checking md5sum and links to tips.

Comment: You are welcome @mohinip :-)