# Ubuntu live usb wont boot, however other distro live usb does

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

So Manjaro, debian, and even ubuntu 16.04 were all successful in a live boot to install from my usb. However, i attempted to do a fresh install of ubuntu 17.10 with a live boot from my usb and my laptop just doesnt detect it and it goes straight to grub. I wanted to test if the usb was corrupt so i reinstalled manjaro on the usb and then started up the system and manjaro was live booted, so the usb is fine, which it should be. I have no idea where to go with this, but i would like to get ubuntu 17.10 on my system. Any ideas?

I used rufus and etcher.

UPDATE: So i reinstalled debian on the usb to live boot off the laptop and when i checked BIOS i noticed that when looking at USB HDD in boot priority, BIOS was actually detecting the name of the usb and listing it whereas when i put Ubuntu on the usb it showed USB HDD: as empty, It wasn't actually detecting a device.

UPDATE 2: Ran in legacy mode, usb was detected and i was able to install 17.10. Only problem is, i didnt know that i couldnt just revert back to uefi and now i just get a black screen with a grub terminal. Im guessing i have to run boot repair, but i cant because the usb isnt being detected in uefi mode.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/674454#674454

Comment: I forgot to add i formatted using dd mode as well, but i guess i will redownload 17.10 and try again because thats the only thing i havnt done from that list.

Comment: `dd` by itself has never been any better than any other method that I have tried. The difference is that the Ubuntu Mini CD iso file is much smaller than the standard Ubuntu iso file (~60MB) so it loads much faster from a USB flash drive.

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 is a short-lived version, supported for only 9 months, while Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has long time support until April 2021. So I would recommend, that you stay with 16.04 LTS, and are happy that it works for you.

Comment: @ubfan1 I used winmd5sum to check and the checksums are the same. followed all the steps in the diagram.Secure boot is disabled, usb hdd is first priority boot.

Comment: @sudodus I know but i prefer gnome over unity personally

Comment: You can try the Ubuntu community flavour **Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS**. I would guess that it will work in your computer. (I think the problem is somehow due to the kernel version (different between the Ubuntu versions) or due to the new features introduced in version 17.10.)

Comment: Now, after 'Update 2', what have you got and what do you want? Is it a dual boot system, or single boot system (only Ubuntu [Gnome])? Is there some other operating system too (Debian or Manjaro or Windows)? Must it boot in UEFI mode? Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu [Gnome] iso file?

Comment: @sudodus Its a 64 bit dual boot system. The thing is when i had ubuntu previously installed i remember it took some time to get it working, i dont remember exactly what i did though. Anyways, i am aiming for a dual boot as well. I need to get this usb recognized in uefi mode.

Comment: It should be a dual boot system with ubuntu and windows.

Comment: Whats blowing my mind right now is that, (i kind of use this as a test case) when i load up manjaro using rufus, DD mode GPT partitioning, pop it into the laptop and UEFI detects it immediately and i have no issues running it. For some reason, Ubuntu is not detected. MBR/GPT partitioning, with ISO or DD mode.

Comment: you need an EFI image for unubtu 17.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe i got it working. So i had to enable F12 boot menu to select a device to boot from rather than prioritizing the boot devices from BIOS. I have an Acer E15. I spent 3 days slaving over this im so done lol

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) I think it can be useful for owners of the same kind of computer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the "missing operating system" message when trying to install the current (L)Ubuntu 18.04. on my old Acer laptop and using UNetBootin to create the Live USB stick.

For me, Robert's solution did not help but simply using another tool to create the Live USB worked: [usb-creator-gtk](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Live-USB/#Installation)