# Getting errors trying to install UNetbootin in order to reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, live-usb, repository, reinstall

I'm new to Linux, and was given a laptop a few months ago with Ubuntu on it, and have been enjoying it so far. I don't do much other than browsing the web, playing Steam, and checking email. Now, I first started noticing any time I tried to update via the Software Center, that I would often get error messages.

The issues basically started when I was having trouble figuring out how to set up this hybrid graphics card setup this laptop has. I was getting bad FPS gaming, so I did some research and found that this laptop has a hybrid setup, so after browsing Google about how to switch from using the onboard card to the Radeon graphics card, I messed up somewhere along the line. Then I basically just went to website after website and tried entering terminal commands from people that had responded to others with the same issue as me.

Eventually, I got it working, but I think that I messed up somewhere and now I get errors doing a wide range of tasks.

Now I want to just completely start fresh and reinstall my OS. The problem is, I am under circumstances where basically I don't have access to USB sticks or CD-ROMs. So, upon doing research, I have followed the instructions given to others trying to do the same thing as me, and I can't get anywhere because I keep getting errors.

I don't really know where to start, so this is an example of an error while trying to install UNetbootin to begin trying to reinstall.

When I enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This is what I get in the terminal:

```
UNetbootin is a cross-platform utility that can create Live USB systems and can load a variety of system utilities or install various Linux distributions and other operating systems without a CD.
Homepage: 
Wiki: 
Downloads: 
Sourceforge: 
Launchpad: 
 More info: 
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpdi5igw02/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpdi5igw02/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key FC91AE7E from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpdi5igw02/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key FC91AE7E: public key "Launchpad PPA for Geza Kovacs" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Then I enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following results:

```
Hit:1 # "random link" that I can't post because I don't have enough reputation to post URLs
Hit:2 random link                 
Hit:3 random link                    
Hit:4 random link          
Hit:5 random link       
Hit:6 random link                  
Get:8 random link      
Hit:9 random link   
Hit:10 random link         
Hit:11 random link      
Get:12 random link 
Get:13 random link 
Hit:14 random link 
Fetched 306 kB in 1s (218 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link  doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link e' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'random link ' doesn't support architecture '1386'
```

That's where I'm hitting a wall. I'm sorry that this may be kind of difficult to narrow down my issues, but I'm unfamiliar with Linux so I don't know exactly what the main issue is that's causing these other tasks to not work. I'm trying to end up being able to end up with a fresh install of Ubuntu or Mint.

Comment: Also, just to add, the one repeating thing I've noticed across the error messages I've been getting via multiple different programs is something along the lines of >libpthread and missing packages? From context clues, it sounds like I'm missing some important files regarding the OS and when programs try and access them, they cant find them.

Comment: It looks like there was a typo when you tried to add i386 architecture to the packages. `1386` is not a architecture but `i386` is.

Comment: So where/what do I do to fix that? Sorry, I'm basically only able to copy and paste what people recommend in Terminal. I have no idea what any of the commands/files they are talking about are.

Comment: Neither of those issues actually break anything though.

Comment: It just seems like somewhere along the line, something got messed up and it's affecting anytime I try to update/install/run certain programs

Answer (score 1):

There are complicated alternative ways to reinstall Ubuntu without using any installation media such as [debootstrap](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot), but getting temporary access to a USB flash drive for a few hours will greatly simplify reinstalling Ubuntu even if you have to borrow one.

You don't need to install anything in order to put the Ubuntu installer on a USB flash drive, because there is already an application for that purpose which is built-in in Ubuntu called Startup Disk Creator. For information on how to use Startup Disk Creator see this question: [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix your apt update issue:

`sudo dpkg --remove-architecture "1386"` or remove the line in `"/var/lib/dpkg/arch"`

Comment: When I entered that, it returned "dpkg: warning: cannot remove non-foreign architecture '1386'"

Comment: Alright try `sudo rm "/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch"` then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: That returns >rm: cannot remove '/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch': No such file or directory

Comment: Alright try `sudo nano "/var/lib/dpkg/arch"` and remove the line with `1386`

Comment: OK, I did that and then removed the line. Then, I tried to re-enter sudo rm "/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch", which returned rm: cannot remove '/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch': No such file or directory. Then I re-entered do apt-get update, which seemed to work. It said,  basically went through a few lines and then the final line says Fetched 306 kB in 1s (228 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: If that doesn't work try loooking at other files dpkg config `ls /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/`

Comment: @eneLon If you saved the file after removing the line just do `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Right, I did that and that seemed to work. It ended saying Fetched 306 kB in 1s (228 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: So since that seemed to be successful, what do I enter next? Thank you so much for taking your time to help me by the way.

Comment: Still with lots of Get/Hit lines though?

Comment: Yes, 14 total. It's not letting me copy and paste because they are URL's and it says I don't have enough Reputation points to post more than 10 URLs.    Ign: 1 then Hit 2-8, then Get 9, Hit 10-11, Get 12-13, Hit 14

Comment: @eneLon Alright thats good. You said there was some error when opening certain applications?

Comment: I just got the "Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error" I snapped a screenshot for you if any of the info this says helps https://imgur.com/a/fMSNs

Comment: Thats a pretty funny error. It seems related to the previous issue. Add the output of `dpkg -C` to your question.

Comment: What do you mean to my question? Also, another main error I get it this https://imgur.com/a/X3hWM  So I'm trying to resolve that, or mainly just get it so I can get UNetbootin to start fresh. Unless it's an easier fix than I think it's going to be, I just felt like doing a fresh install would be easier.

Comment: So when I try to run that game, I get the error from my last post. Then, when I enter sudo apt-get install unetbootin To install UNetbootin, I get this back - 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libopenal1:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: @eneLon Not sure about that one but try this: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture "i386"` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386`

Comment: @eneLon The pthread error is pretty typical depending if you're using the proprietary driver.