# What is the download size of Ubuntu latest version?

Tags: system-installation

I have limited internet bandwidth.
I would like to know the download size of the latest version of Ubuntu.

Can anyone confirm which is it?

Comment: Why don't you look at a [mirror in India](http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu-releases/17.10.1/)? It shows 1502576640 bytes for the ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso. I figured that out in less than a minute.

Comment: Go e.g. to the [releases site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) select the one you need (LTS or not), follow the link, scroll down to the iso file, read its size. Note after you may need to download and add additional packages. You may want to use similar sites for different flavour (kubuntu...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest release of Ubuntu is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS now, its size is **1.8 GB**.
 The final stable release has been just released, so it is recommended to give it some time before trying it for professional use.

Answer (score 4):

<s>When I checked in my Downloads folder the size of the ISO file of the latest release of Ubuntu is 1.5GB which will fit on a >=2GB USB flash drive or a DVD.</s> The [Ubuntu 18.04 iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) is <s>2.0GB</s> 2.3GB, so you would be better off using a 4GB or larger USB flash drive for Ubuntu 18.04. The [Ubuntu 23.04 iso](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) is 4.2GB, so you would be better off using an 8GB or larger USB flash drive for Ubuntu 23.04.

- The [Ubuntu 23.04 iso](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) is 4.2GB.
- The [Ubuntu 22.10 iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/22.10/) is 3.8GB.
- The [Ubuntu 22.04 iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/) is 3.4GB.
- The [Ubuntu 20.04 iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/) is 2.7GB.
- The [Ubuntu 18.04 iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) is 2.3GB.

Download the SHA256SUMS file for whatever Ubuntu ISO that you download so that you can verify the ISO file before using it.

The latest release of Ubuntu is 17.10. The SHA256SUMS file for Ubuntu 17.10 is at [this webpage](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/). The latest Long Term Support (LTS) release of Ubuntu is 16.04. Regular releases of Ubuntu are supported by updates for 9 months after the release date and LTS releases are supported for 5 years after the release date.

Comment: Let me have a try

Comment: Guide to creating a bootable Ubuntu installation USB flash drive from the Ubuntu ISO: [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)