# zsync download limit can be increased..?

Tags: zsync

zsync download limit can be increased...?
because, i'am currently downloading a ubuntu *iso files named lunar, and if reaching size more than 4GB can causing zsync making a error log with like the following:

error: file too large.

Comment: That has nothing to do with zsync. You are using a filesystem that has a 4Gb file size limit. Means you are not using ext4.  Are you using Ubuntu to download this? Using fat32 per haps? Please edit the question and add what FS you are using to store the download.

Comment: FYI: I'm downloading the *lunar* dailies using scripts without issues (*like prior cycles using `zsync`*),  which includes current files >5GB for some, <3GB for others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update an ISO with zsync?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54241/how-do-i-update-an-iso-with-zsync)

Comment: yes, currently i'am using fat32 partition to store the download file, and using ubuntu for downloading the file.

Comment: Your file-system cannot store the larger files; so the issue isn't with `zsync`, but your chosen storage location is incompatible with files that large.  FYI:  Some other *lunar* images can be used; eg. Lubuntu is small enough - https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/ but otherwise you'll need a different save location.

Comment: okay, thank you all, for solving my bad problems... :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the download size of Ubuntu latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007247/what-is-the-download-size-of-ubuntu-latest-version)