# How do I install Ubuntu without a USB or a CD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 17.10, wubi, unetbootin

I want to install Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 on my Windows 10 computer. Problem is, I tried to use Unetbootin and when I selected it on the OS menu, it displayed an error message saying to insert a Windows 10 disk (even though I have already got Windows 10 installed) and showed me the file I "was missing". So I tried to find the software called *Wubi* which apparently is on the download page for Ubuntu, but I couldn't find it. I don't think it's even on the ISO. Can you please help? I don't want to use a VM.

Update: I have finally gotten a USB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) and you are right, the Ubuntu 17.10 ISO file does not include wubi and UNetbootin is not so good for making bootable Ubuntu installation media.

Comment: Wubi is not supported on Windows 8 or 10. You can either (1) install Ubuntu as a separate OS and use Dual Boot (i.e. at start-up time, choose which OS you want to boot) or (2) use VirtualBox on Windows 10 and install Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Comment: It is possible but rather difficult to install Ubuntu without a USB drive or DVD disk. Why do you want to install without it? Is there no USB port and  no DVD drive on the computer? Can you connect two drives internally (for example two hard disk drives)? Can you use another computer with USB or DVD to do the installation? Do you mean version 7.10 (passed end of life long ago) or the current version 17.10.1?

Comment: It looks like you were able to create a bootable USB stick with Unetbootin. Did you?
But when you are trying to install Ubuntu with this bootable USB stick it 
asks for the signature file for Windows 10 because you have still "secure boot" enabled in the systems BIOS.
Try to go in the systems BIOS and verify that "secure boot" is disabled.
(When "secure boot" is enabled it will check for a predefined signature on the boot medium, which is typically only available for Windows boot/install media.)

Comment: My Windows 10 does have a virtual DVD drive I can mount to, but other than that I don't have any spare DVD-Rs to write to, nor any USB sticks. And Netboot seems to complicated to use. Are there any alternate downloads for 7.10 that includes an installer?

Comment: 1. A **USB pendrive** is rather cheap nowadays, and it can be reused for new purposes (which is different from standard DVD disks). The size should be at least 2 GB. If you don't want to buy one, maybe you can borrow a USB pendrive from a friend, relative or colleague. (It will be overwritten, but can be restored afterwards to a standard storage device.) ; 2. Please consider a **current version** of Ubuntu. The version 7.10 passed end of life years ago, and is no longer supported.

Comment: My mistake, my version of Ubuntu uses 17.10.1, not 7.10.

Comment: That's good (17.10.1) :-) Anyway, iso files of Ubuntu contain an installer, but you should start by installing the iso file to a USB pendrive (or DVD disk). All other alternatives are more difficult.

Comment: Update: I have finally gotten a USB. Thanks for the help anyway. I appreciate it.

Comment: Good luck using your USB stick to create a live system and using that live system to install Ubuntu :-) You are welcome to ask new questions, if there are problems ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 2):

### Boot Ubuntu on Windows UEFI computer without USB or CD

- Use Windows Disk Management to create FAT32 partition 3GB or larger.
- Copy/Paste contents of ISO file to new partition.
- Reboot pressing F12 and select UEFI Ubuntu.
- Continue to Install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is to use Rufus to install your Ubuntu image on a USB stick. You can find it here https://rufus.akeo.ie/
It's like Unetbootin but more efficient (in my opinion). When i use it, it doesn't ask to insert a windows 10 disk. (And i don't understand why Unetbootin ask this)

Otherwise, you can install Ubuntu over network with the Netboot install. you can find some help on the official Ubuntu website here -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

But be aware that is not easy like the USB installation.

Comment: While the Rufus software may be a useful alternative, it is still about creating a USB stick. 
However this may resolve the issue.

The netboot option on the other hand requires either a netboot medium (CD/DVD/USB) and access to internet to access the repositories or a PXE enabled networkcard on the computer and a separate prepared Linux-server with DHCP server and tftp server.

Comment: Rufus is still about creating an USB stick yes. But i think if i have read well that is not a problem. Because he was trying unsuccessfully to make one with Unetbootin. Maybe it is just a "secure boot" problem. Anyway, if he really doesn't want to use USB or CD/DVD for any reason, the netboot option seems to be the last one.

Comment: My Windows 10 does have a virtual DVD drive I can mount to, but other than that I don't have any spare DVD-Rs to write to, nor any USB sticks. And Netboot seems to complicated to use. Are there any alternate downloads for 7.10 that includes an installer?

Comment: You can't install your Ubuntu (or any operating system) with a virtual drive in Windows 10. And why do you want the 7.10 edition? For some test? Did you consider trying a Virtual Machine for that?

Comment: @Anaussie *17.10