# Downloading Ubuntu to SD card

Tags: downloads, drive

Helle. I have small eMMC drive on ASUS vivobook l401na. How do download ubuntu to sd card to try it as my windows leaves hardly any space on drive?

Comment: You can boot from an SD card, when connected via most (but not all) USB adapters, and in some cases also via the built-in card reader. See these links and links from them, [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). An SD card works like a USB pendrive, and the same instructions can be used. (It is actually easier to use a USB pendrive than an SD card, but both are possible to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso) Follow the same instructions for making bootable USB media for installing Ubuntu, except use your SD card instead of using a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ubuntu booting from DVD or USB(same as SD). To make bootable USB-SD use program `unetbootin`. It writes CD/DVD image to USB and make it bootable so you can try it live, or install from it.