# Install USB stick not booting regardless of distro 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, live-usb

I have a Walgreen Infintive USB drive I titled INSTALL, which I use to... install things. I've used it to install multiple Ubuntu flavors, and maybe even Linux Mint?? Anyway,first and foremost-- this isn't an Ubuntu-specific question, but it relates to my using unetbootin to make install drives on Ubuntu 16.04.....

My drive won't boot. When I turn off my Yoga 2 11, and press the BIOS button, then go down to boot manager, the Walgreen infinitive shows up, I select it, and get the typical (installed to my HDD) GRUB menu. I've tried Windows 10, I've tried Ubuntu 16.04..... Linux Mint, LMDE, Ubuntu (whatever flavor), Fedora, Debian, etc. will not boot from my drive.

I have done multiple FULL formats and re-installs with unetbootin (with both Windows and Ubuntu) AND Fedora Media writer(on Windows 10), to no avail. I was wondering if I could have a faulty drive??... The only thing I haven't tried is to boot from my USB on another machine, but I feel like that isn't really necessary, since I've installed Ubuntu many a times with this drive.

Oh one more thing-- the drive has always seemed a bit faulty, like it hasn't always installed all of Ubuntu's little pieces (for example, I can't switch to TTY1/2/3/4/etc this time around for some reason) or something even when it was working. My REAL question, getting to the point, is, CAN I even have a faulty install drive??? Is this my computer??

I keep meaning to try this USB on another computer, but I'm almost positive it's the drive, and just want to be reassured that it's the drive, and the problem can be fixed with a USB drive purchase. Sorry for the essay, I appreciate any input, and sorry to the community if this isn't Ubuntu-specific enough.

Comment: I would start by testing the drive in other computers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A faulty USB flash drive is a frequent cause of being unable to boot successfully from an Ubuntu live USB flash drive. Reformatting the faulty USB flash driver will frequently not solve this problem either. There are a few common software solutions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/674454#674454), but they do not always work either. The most common solution is to replace the USB flash drive.

Comment: +1. @Robert Sederholm,  See also this link, [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed to justify spending money on another drive!! Lol.

Comment: Just an update if you're interested.... My BIOS is like, shot. My walgreen infinitive shows up on the boot menu when it's not even plugged in, I can't even go into BIOS settings, and it was totally not the usb drive. I know how to do troubleshoooting.... I think my drive is actually good. I will, however, keep your answer accepted because it was a good answer, and can help others.
I'm getting a new Desktop PC no worries guys