# Ubuntu Bootable USB boots back to macOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I created a Ubuntu bootable USB with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit for my Mac based on [this tutorial.](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0)

When I go to the boot manager by holding the option/alt key and select the drive, the Mac just ignores the usb and boots back to MacOS Sierra.

My usb is a sandisk 16GB and I am using a 2016 MacBook Pro without touch bar.

Comment: The Mac may not be ignoring you. If the Mac does not find a bootable drive where you told it to look, then it tries other drives. Remake the USB.

Comment: I remade the usb multiple times and the EFI boot loader detects the drive but when I select the drive it boots back to macOS

Comment: @AmrEhab Have you tried any other ways? Like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/)? Or any [other USB drives](https://askubuntu.com/a/1019223/250300)?

Comment: yes I did try UNetbootin and I tried to make the usb from the terminal but none of them works.