# Ubuntu Server 18.04: Installation restarting after choosing Disk

Tags: boot, server, usb, 18.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer from a USB stick.

I've created the usb with two different softwares:

- MultiSystem
- Etcher

On step 6 of the installations process it asks to select an "Entier Disk" or "Manual", both answers take me to the same issue:

- Suddenly an page error page is shown, I cannot see the errors, and in less than 1 seconds resets the installation process and goes again to the first step

I've tested the ISO and downloaded a few times with the same result.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you [verify the integrity](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the disc image(s) used as source to create the installation media?

Comment: Yes, I followed the tutorial of the link you suggested. At the end I installed the Desktop version without problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)