# I lost all my linux data on reboot. :( [xubuntu, unetbooted alongside preinstalled windows 7]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-7, reboot

I always run my laptop on windows 7, which was already pre-installed.
I used UnetBootin to install xubuntu 18.04 alongside windows 7 without a usb/cd.
I don't have a usb/cd at the moment. I installed xubuntu, used it for a good two hours, installed lots of stuff, personalized it etc. and suddenly my browser freezed and it resulted in a over-all system lag. I had to force restart it. When i booted in again, i noticed no files that i created - nor the programs i installed with sudo apt install are there anymore. It simply "factory reset" my whole ubuntu files and i don't think there's a way to recover them anymore, so is there a way to prevent deleting all files from xubuntu at reboot?

all windows files are perfectly ok.

Is there a way to prevent this? Please. Also, please keep in mind i am not a fluent linux user, i just wanted to test it out. And suddenly this happened and i think i lost all my hope.

Comment: Next time install Ubuntu from a USB and it won't happen again: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/674454#674454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear about that.

Sounds like unetbootin doesn't use persistence. I don't use unetbootin as it has been known to not play nice with Linux.

I like to keep things simple so you can try this:

Once you address your usb/cd drive issues you could try setting up a virtual machine (VM) and running ubuntu in that environment as opposed to what you were doing with unetbootin.

If you get the drive issues fixed try using ubuntu in a live setting for a while or install directly on bare metal for best results. There may be other solutions to your issue with users that are more familiar with unetbootin.

Xubuntu is a great distro and glad you liked it :)

Have fun

Comment: How do i set up a VM? and does it run without turning on windows first?

Comment: There are 3 ways to use a VM, set up a virtual box, use QEMU for ARM, or set up a KVM. All of which are detailed and too long to post here. There are plenty of tutorials in the wild to help you. But the best advice would be to get access to your usb/cd drive and go from there.