# Downloading Ubuntu on an old Dell desktop

Tags: xubuntu, downloads

These are steps I've taken:

- I deleted windows OS from PC.
- Downloaded Ubuntu from other computer, then used ISO opener and installed on USB.
- Used `winsetupusb` to format to FAT.
- Plugged it into USB and turned on the PC.
- Pressed <kbd>ESC</kbd> to open up boot options, chose USB flash.
- Got message saying minimal Bash-like line editing is supported. For the fist word, <kbd>TAB</kbd> lists possible command completions etc...

Can anyone provide some help?
I tried to take a picture, but it said it's to large.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

So what OS does that another computer have from which you downloaded the OS?
Okay, by the way follow my steps:

***If using Ubuntu***

1. install unetbootin from [here](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html)
2. Select the ISO option and locate the iso file and select it.
3. ***IMPORTANT** Select USB Drive from "Type" and select your drive if you have multiple drives attached to your computer.
4. Press OK and wait for the process to complete.
5. Remove the drive if a prompt shows that the process is complete.

***If using windows(any version)***:

1. Download and install unetbootin from [here](https://unetbootin.github.io/)
2. Do the same steps from above above step 2(lol)
3. Remove the usb when process is complete.

***INSTALLATION:***

1. Plug the usb after powering off the computer.
2. Power on the pc and select the usb from boot options( Press f8,f10,f12 or del to get boot options).
3. Select usb drive from boot options.
4. Another boot option comes up which is created by unetbootin.
5. Select "Install Ubuntu" from the options and press enter.
6. Complete the process of installation.
7. Reboot computer and remove usb drive.
8. Run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade so that the softwares are uptodate.