# Installing Ubuntu Desktop to Windows. Downloaded file from website, can't get it to run

Tags: system-installation

I just downloaded the most recent version of Ubuntu Desktop to my new computer modem that currently has windows installed. The file that downloaded from the website is saved to my desktop. I cannot get the installer to run. When I open the file there is a bunch of files and I tried clicking on a few, but can't seem to get the installer to run...
HELP?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Comment: It is on my desktop... Do I just drag it onto a USB? I don't see how that would change anything. I am not a computer wiz...so could use some clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Can I just run it off the desktop, or do I have to configure it to a USB?

Comment: Try to follow the steps in the tutorial. Once Ubuntu is on the USB, you can run Ubuntu from the USB (which is the next tutorial linked in the series.)

Comment: ok, thanks. Will I always need to USB plugged into the computer to run it on Ubuntu or can I install it and unplug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Ubuntu is not a Windows program you can just click install. It is an alternative operating system, and it must be installed as outlined in the installation guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: _"Ubuntu is not a Windows program"_ => although true, this distinction is somewhat muddied by WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which you can install while Windows is there & running and use both at once ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 ). Its usefulness (imho) is somewhat limited in terms of what can be accessed (programs, files) from the Linux "subsystem" vs Windows directly. A third option is to run docker on Windows. A forth is to run VirtualBox & run Linux in a Virtual Machine. For basic GNU/bash shell on Windows, there's also Cygwin (eg via Swan) or Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

(Adding as an answer, because to long for a comment): *"Will I always need the USB plugged into the computer to run it?"*

Once Ubuntu is properly installed on [a *bootable* USB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) (note: this replaces everything else on the USB drive!), then you can (1) run Ubuntu directly from the USB (the USB is the main "hard drive", instead of Windows), and then *optionally* (2) install Ubuntu onto your computer. With just the first option, you can play around with Ubuntu as if it were installed, and see if it works on your hardware, without actually installing anything. But before actually *using* it for *real* work (or play!), then you must ["install" Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0). You can do this while Ubuntu is running off the USB -- there's an icon on the desktop that will say "Install Ubuntu" (see linked tutorial). On the next reboot, you can choose either Windows or Ubuntu to run (they won't be running at the same time!). This is what's referred to as a "dual boot" configuration, and is most useful if you want to use Ubuntu as your main OS and rarely use Windows. If you just occasionally want to run some Linux program (like Jupyter notebook or such), then it may be preferable to run [docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) or [Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine (VM)](https://www.lifewire.com/run-ubuntu-within-windows-virtualbox-2202098) -- the simpler option to start would be to install Ubuntu on Virtual Box for Windows. In fact, running Ubuntu in a VM may be a good first exercise before setting up a dual boot configuration. In any case, be sure to fully back up your Windows PC before starting anything (not just your files, but rather create a [full system backup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-full-backup-windows-10)).