# ubuntu live persistense created usb not saving the data

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I recently made a bootable USB of Ubuntu 18.0 LTS with unetbootin and Linux live USB creator and universal USB to save the settings and data. but every time I reboot my system my settings and data is gone. I created a new user account but this also didn't work.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), which can create a persistent live drive with a `casper-rw` **partition** and use the whole drive space.

Comment: My results with trying various Live/Persistent installers with Ubuntu 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/1069189#1069189 the results are sometimes different than with 16.04.