# Reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 LTS i386, 32 bit

Tags: 16.04, lts

After several years of beeing very happy with Ubuntu, happily using the 16.04 LTS i386, 32 bit for some time.
There was an option popping up to upgrade to 18.04 LTS. I was hesitating for some time but decided to upgrade. Immediately after it was finished I noticed it was completely IMPOSSIBLE to connect to internet, wifi or ethernet. I could see the routers and their speeds BUT no connection!!!!
So I erased the 18.04. 
Now trying to install the 16.04.5 i386, 32 bit from the DVD I have created but that does not work completely. 
Halfway through the installation, beside windows, I get an ERROR-message and the installation is cancelled!
I will try to run this DVD as a trial-version, without installation, and see what will happens.
Open to suggestions!

Comment: Maybe try running a [live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/) of a *buntu 18.04 edition that supports 32-bit architecture and check if the ethernet and wifi work in the live USB session before installing it. Ubuntu 18.04 supports only 64-bit, but Ubuntu MATE 18.04 supports 32-bit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*I could see the routers and their speed*", but if you could for example `ping` your router (or see it) but not the web, your issue was possibly DNS (or converting addresses like google.com to their IP numbers) If this, it's a routing issue & easily fixed. Lubuntu currently is alone still supporting 32bit beyond 18.04.  As for 16.04 LTS, did you verify the download? (md5sum or sha256sum) I'd recommend viewing https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu  (the 15-30 secs it takes to check download saves hours of debugging if download issue)