# Unable To Install To USB

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, live-usb, usb-installation

I am currently using [Zorin OS 12.4 Core](https://zorinos.com/download/) as the only Operating System on my [ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 4 (20FC)](https://www.ebay.com/i/202532490529?chn=ps). I am trying install either Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS or Ubuntu 18.10 on my pc and it says that that I need either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media. I tried to get it onto a USB but it won't let me install it to a USB. How do I install either Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS or Ubuntu 18.10 on to my USB? [DownloadUbuntuDesktop.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8rei.jpg) [ImageBurningSetup.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Sld.jpg)

Comment: And your USB is how big? And are we talking install here or creating an installer?

Comment: My USB is 64GB. I wanna get either Ubuntu LTS OS or Ubuntu OS on to my my pc as the only OS on my pc while removing all other OSs on the pc as well. I have get either Ubuntu LTS OS or Ubuntu OS onto the USB first. I did it when I installed ZorinOS but it wont let me do it for Ubuntu LTS OS or Ubuntu OS...idk why

Comment: And what is the error message!

Comment: I tried to pick a location to install the OS...the location would be USB...but there is no option for USB. I am lost. I need help with this! I would like to complete this by the end of the day. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8rei.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Sld.jpg

Comment: Are you trying to install while running Zorin (which is a linux distro)? You can install [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Linux_distros_where_mkusb_works) and use it to create a USB boot drive. The simple way is to **clone** from the iso file to the USB pendrive.

Comment: I'm confused on what i click to install mkusb...I'm also confused on what i do

Comment: Plz help me with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: I wrote an answer that I think will help. Ask again, if necessary. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

**For a simple installer flash drive that will boot in UEFI:**

1. Insert flash drive, note it's location, likely `sdb`.
2. Download an Ubuntu ISO file.
3. `cd` to its directory.
4. Run in terminal:

   ```
   sudo dd if=isofilename.iso of=/dev/sdb
   ```

   (assuming `sdb` is the USB)
5. The process will take a while.
6. When done, boot Ubuntu from the USB flash drive in UEFI mode and install.

Comment: **The `dd` method is the general advice, that works in all linux distros and hybrid iso files.** It is simple, but it is very important to double check the device letter of the output, because `dd` does what you tell it to do without questions and can easily overwrite valuable data, just because of a typing error.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `mkusb` with the following commands in a terminal window. Zorin is similar enough to Ubuntu so that the same commands work (to install and run `mkusb`).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

You can start mkusb

- *from the menu* or
- *from the command line* in a terminal window

  ```
  mkusb file.iso
  ```

  or easier (more directly to version 12, `dus`

  ```
  dus file.iso
  ```

and it will help you to identify and select the target device.

---

There are more details at [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)