# Burning Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit iso in various ways but can never boot to it

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, livedvd

I want to try Lubuntu 18.04 LTS before installing next to Windows:

- I have downloaded the 32-bit Desktop-Iso-Image from https://lubuntu.me/downloads/
- I have tried to burn DVD using Start Medium Creator from System Tools of a Lubuntu 16.04 computer. But the dialog does not show the DVD Drive?
- I burned the DVD using Xf Burn, but computer (Boot Sequence starting with DVD) does not boot on reboot?
- I burned the iso-image to a USB-Stick (FAT32) with UNetBootin on a windows computer.
  Also on reboot the computer does not boot from the USB-Stick?

Very frustrating; what is going wrong or what do I need to do?
Would appreciate step by step instructions.

Comment: Did you change the boot priorities of the devices you want to boot from in the bios of your pc?

Comment: If you are just "trying out" Ubuntu, maybe you should use a virtual machine to see if you like Ubuntu before modifying you had drive configurations.

Comment: Yes I changed boot piorities > USB > DVD > HDD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 32bit ISO then your machine is old.
So it uses normal BIOS instead of UEFI.
You have to set the boot drive priority from e.g [HDD, USB and then DVD] to [DVD, USB and then HDD] in Bios, save BIOS settings and reboot with DVD or USB attached.

Try hitting DEL or F2 (typical keys to enter BIOS) for entering BIOS after powering on the PC until the post screen appears. Or check your PC manual how to enter BIOS.

Another possibility not booting from DVD is missing [El Torito Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard)) of your drive (or BIOS).

So i recommend to use a USB stick. Try Etcher windows app to create a bootable Linux USB ISO drive. It's very easy and works.
On Linux there's usually a "Drives" app to rebuild an ISO to a USB stick.

Comment: I had already set the Boot Order in BIOS to 1) USB    2) DVD 3) HDD                                                              Linux offers the start medium creator, which I also tried, but all unsuccessful