# How to make bootable usb stick for Ubuntu Studio Eoan Ermine 19.10

Tags: 19.10

I need to make a bootable usb drive using the official released iso image for Ubuntu Studio Eoan Ermine 19.10.

I tried MultiBootUSB, dd, Gnome Disk Utility.

MultiBootUSB shows me a message that this is a memdisk iso and not supported.

Comment: Given at the bottom of the page: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop Look for "How to create a bootable USB stick on <your OS>".

Comment: Possibly also useful (*to ensure the ISO file is flawless in case that's your issue*) - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: FedonKadifeli, there's the garbage `Startup Disk Creator`. It don't work, also erase whole stick though I need save only little iso, and has low SoftwareCenter's rating.

Comment: guiverc, I verified the file, it's ok. And I downloaded via torrent, where is additional checksum.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, Ubuntu 19.10 looks raw and unstable, there are reports of installation problems. Created the issue on Multibootusb repo https://github.com/mbusb/multibootusb/issues/478.