# Not able to install any operating system

Tags: 18.04

Every time i try to install Ubuntu or Linux mint it will give me same error the photo is attached please have a look , and help me 
thanks for your kindness

[image]

Comment: Please don't solicit advice for operating systems other than Ubuntu or its official flavors.

Comment: the screenshot i shared is of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, it was my first choice, but it didn't get through so i tried LinuxMint , BUT ACTUALLY I WANT TO INSTALL UBUNTU 18.04.

Comment: Would try to download again, use a different program for putting ISO on DVD/USB and or using a different DVD writer or different brand/type of DVD.

Comment: i downloaded it two times and tried loading it with different methods and with different USB drives still not working 1. method was Rufus 2. method was from command prompt in windows 8.1

Comment: Did you verify the downloaded ISO matches its source? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 Did you do an integrity check of the installing DVD? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck?action=show&redirect=CDIntegrityCheck If you did and it still fails, you have a hardware problem; unplug/replug the drive inside the PC, and if the problem persists, run a hardware diagnostic.

Comment: Is secure boot disabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)