# No display on Ubuntu 18.04 installation

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, graphics, radeon, rufus

I was trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10. I have following configuration-

- Partition- GPT
- Motherboard firmware- UEFI
- Processor- Ryzen 5 3500
- MoBo- B450 Mortar Max
- Graphics- Gigabyte Radeon RX 570
- SSD- WD Green 480 GB M.2 2280 SATA
- RAM -G.SKILL Ripjaws 16GB DDR4 3000 MHz

I have tried to make a bootable USB using Rufus and Universal-USB-Installer, both. But after booting from USB and clicking `Install Ubuntu` or `Try Ubuntu without installing`, I do not get any display (just blank screen). 
I believe that my monitor is not getting signal from graphics card because I am able to listen Up-Down arrow clicks from my speaker.

My monitor is connected through a HDMI cable to graphics card and the motherboard has an updated firmware with the most recent v26 version.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)