# 18.04: System install fails with filesystem error in LiveUSB

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

Previously, I had Windows 10 installed on my PC. Due to some problems, I thought of shifting to Ubuntu. By following [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2018/08/29/beginners-guide-how-to-install-ubuntu-linux/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwjFgdf4huHnAhVRzDgGHTzOATYQFjALegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1KpomMpk8sqxlH_4IP0X5j&ampcf=1) post, I had downloaded the 18.04.4 version's iso file and used unetbootin to burn it onto a pendrive.

The burn was successful and I could boot Ubuntu in live mode. Thinking everything to be all right, I started the installation process. After configuring the installation, a message was shown that `We're sorry, Ubuntu installer has crashed`. Then when I tried to *check the disk for errors* from the boot menu, it said that `error found in 1 files`. It's most probably the *casper/filesystem.squashfs* file that's causing the error.
[image]

Now I don't have even the Windows OS because in the process, my HDD got formatted. It's my mistake that I don't know much about disk partitioning. What to do now? I am still able to boot into the live mode from the pendrive, only problem is that I can't save anything to disk. Can I burn a new ISO to that pendrive from this live mode?

Comment: For starters, you can format the disk, using gparted or the Disks utility. If the problem is really the USB installer, you can store the ubuntu ISO in the created partition, and then with another USB, you can burn the ISO. Don't use unetbootin. Follow [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview).

Comment: If in doubt, I can write an answer.

Comment: Can't I use the same USB device? According to my knowledge, the live OS gets loaded in the RAM, isn't it?

Comment: Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Comment: No, you can't use the same USB that you booted from.

Comment: The write to media either failed, or your downloaded ISO was imperfect (did you check it?  see link provided by K7AAY.  I find the write to thumb-drive the most flawed (but I write 5-9 a week) and that integrity check detects those, allowing a re-write. In most cases just repeating the write (`dd`, `mkusb`) will fix it, if it repeats multiple times your writing tool is possibly flawed or media is actually faulty (if thumb drive; just replace it).

Comment: Can I rely on the disk checking tool that comes with the installer? If that doesn't detect any error, can I be sure that the installation will succeed?

Comment: I had re-downloaded the Ubuntu installer and it worked. Also, this time I didn't used unetBootin, I used Universal USB Installer for windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now successfully installed Ubuntu and checked that everything is working perfectly. According to me, either there might have been a problem in the downloaded iso file or the UNetBootin software. Then I had redownloaded the iso and used **Universal USB installer** to install it.

For those who will be installing Ubuntu, I have some advice for them to prevent any problems :

- After downloading the iso file, check whether the file have downloaded properly or not by matching the checksum. See this https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview
- Before installing Ubuntu, select **Check disk for errors** from the boot menu to check for errors in the installation media.
- Install Ubuntu on a separate partition in the main disk to avoid any data loss.