# Can't boot into live USB

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, gparted, 19.04, bios

I have Ubuntu 19.04 currently and I created a live USB of GParted using Balena. I want to boot into it, but even though I restarted my machine and put the priority of USB higher in hte boot order in BIOS, the starting screen does not give me option to boot into it.

Comment: Could be a bad ISO download or burn if you are using GParted Live.  19.04 is not supported any more, so you will need to upgrade to 19.10.  Ubuntu Live USBs have gparted on them(not installed when you install OS).

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months

Comment: You may also downgrade to 18.04, it is a long term release, (LTS) and is supported until 2028. 19.10 is only supported for another four months .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441)

Comment: As I understand the op is trying to install the 355MB gparted-live-1.1.0-1-amd64.iso onto USB. The GParted Live ISO has more features than the version of GParted that comes with Ubuntu. The fact that he is has 18.04 on his computer does not enter into it, he is not installing to 18.04, only running Etcher from it. (There is also an Etcher version for Windows). The OP should confirm that he is using the release that suits his computer, (i686, i686-pae or amd64), and check the checksum. https://gparted.org/download.php and https://gparted.org/liveusb.php

Comment: I used Etcher for Linux running in Ubuntu to install GParted amd64 to a 2GB USB2 drive and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I couldn't go through the comments earlier. After studying the comments, turns out the EFI was in uppercase in the file while I had been typing "efi" according to the tutorials.

Regardless of that, the error showed that it was a bad image and could not be loaded.