# Re Install Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I have purchased a GPD Pocket linux version via ebay and the boot up asks the following

ubuntu unlock disk sda3_crypt

Now the previous owner asks me to just re install ubuntu. How do i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441)

Comment: Remember to provide accurate feedback about the purchase on ebay: "*Item was encrypted and unusable without additional work*"

Answer (score 0):

If you have an USB and another pc you could make an usb bootable with an linux image of the SO that you want in the pc.

You will need another pc to do that, download the ISO of the operative system and a program like [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)(if the another PC has windows) or a program like MULTISYSTEM if you have linux in the other PC(i think that it should be on official repositories or you can download it via internet; i never made it on linux and i cant help with that,sorry)

After you have the USB bootable, you need enter to the BIOS of the pc too boot and start using the pendrive, and install linux over the current SO, formating the disk.