# Ubuntu won't start from USB surface pro 6

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-10, surface

I have downloaded Ubuntu and used Rufus to load this ISO and create a bootable USB drive.
Everytime I go to reboot my computer in USB mode--ubuntu will not run. It keeps defaulting to Windows 10. 
I rearranged the boot order to prioritize USB boot and it still will not boot from USB. 
Any other ideas for me to run this alongside windows 10 on my surface pro 6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

Rufus downloads some boot files to be booted instead of those who are in the ISO.
It did not work for me too, try [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ubuntu did you download ?
Also did you make sure to save settings before exiting the boot setup ?

P.S. I don't have enough reputation to make comment so,i have to ask this way .