# i select the usb boot option from Bios it opens up all the files from the usb, asks me for a specific file to boot

Tags: boot, usb, windows-10, alienware

Adding a USB boot option, after selecting the USB boot

[image: img_boot_option]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso) related question: [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764/)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate the `BIOS` to an `EFI` file. 
You should be able to find it in the folders on your bootable device (USB stick?)...
Check the `/boot/` and `/EFI/` folders on your screenshot.

Hope it helps you out.