# Problems with Linux Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I am kinda noob, sorry if this is dumb question or I forgot to mention some details.

I tried installing Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but couldn't find a pendrive. Apparently it was possible without it, so I did it using some tutorials from internet and friend's knowledge (I did it much as in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/T5wElGrnUiI), but when I selected unetbootin in boot menu I get Ubuntu loading screen and it says "Checking disks: x% complete".
Then is was saying "./boot/grub/x: No such file or directory", and it took quite a lot of time to finish.
Also I couldn't stop it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
And I didn't see that part in any tutorial, idk what was that.

After it was finished I did it mostly like in that tutorial from link above, but I selected Use as: Ext4. (04:05 in that tutorial)
(I installed it on disk E, which was empty)
Installation was completed, and I removed unetbootin, but then I have no boot menu, I can't launch linux, it just automatically launches windows when I turn on computer :/
And now I can't see disk E in windows, but I checked in disk manager and it says disk E has 100% free space.
So does it mean linux installation failed?
What did I do wrong, why it doesn't work, and how to make it work?

Comment: The recommended way of installing Ubuntu at the official ubuntu.com website is with a live Ubuntu USB. For more information read[What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/).

Comment: The advantage of that method is you don't need a pendrive, the disadvantage is that it seldom works. If you don't have a pendrive or smart phone try my answer below

Answer (score 2):

### Using Universal USB Installer to install Ubuntu Live to a partition on your HDD

- Download **Universal USB Installer**: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
- Create a small, (3GB), FAT32, (or NTFS), partition on a **secondary** msdos hard drive. Installing on the Windows Drive will overwrite the Windows bootloader.
- Start UUI and specify the Ubuntu ISO you wish to install, select `All Drives Shown`, then select the new target partition. Do not select Format Drive

[image]

- Select `Create` and let the installation complete.
- Reboot and select the new Live internal drive for installing Ubuntu.
- The Live partition will boot in either BIOS or UEFI mode. When using it to install Ubuntu, make sure to boot it in the same mode Windows is installed in.
- On the first boot run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to the GRUB menu.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Download Ubuntu from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Step 2 (only if you use a USB stick or don't have a dvd writer):
Download Rufus  from http://rufus.ie

Step 3:
Make your USB stick ready by selecting your iso in rufus and press START
or (slow way)
Make a dvd ready by burning your iso to a dvd disk

Step 4:
Boot from the usb stick or dvd drive

Step 5:
Press install Ubuntu, select your keyboard and connect to a network

Step 6:
Do a custom disk partitioning, select your drive, make an ext4 partition and set the mounting point to "/". On the bottom, select your windows boot drive to install GRUB

Step 7:
Select your time zone, set up your account, and let it install

I think step 6 is where it got wrong, so be careful there. If you don't select the correct grub installation location, the Ubuntu installation will fail and you will be rederected to Windows

These are the seven steps I used every time I tried installing Ubuntu, they've always worked for me.

Comment: I strongly suggest installing from a DVD (and not from USB stick) whenever possible. From my experience, there is much less potential problems when installing from DVD than from USB.

Comment: I don't think so. DVD's are pretty slow, and they can get scratched in the dvd player/writer. I always used a usb stick, and it works well every time, except if I forgot one step...

Comment: @raj: I install Ubuntu one way or another almost every day, I have not used a DVD in years. DVD's are slow and get scratched, and they cost money. Few computers come with DVD burners nowadays.

Comment: As I see from posts on this forum, people often have trouble to get Ubuntu to boot correctly after installing from USB. Some of them turn out to be explicitly related to GRUB being written somehow to USB instead of HDD. There is no such possibility when installing from DVD, therefore I think that for an inexperienced user, who is doing this for the first time, DVD installation is easier.