# Using ubuntu 20.20.4, want ubuntudde. Downloaded the rufus.exe to usb but get an error message from archive manager when trying to open?

Tags: apt, usb

I am new to Linux. Using ubuntu 20.04, want ubuntudde. Downloaded the rufus.exe to usb but get an error message from archive manager when trying to open?

I have tried F2,4 6 8 12 and DEL but cannot boot from the usb. Now I am told I cant run exe-files from ubuntu so how to install ubuntudde? I have nothing windowsrelated left on this computer.

Comment: You can't run .exe files in Linux

Comment: Rufus runs on Windows, not Linux. You can make Ubuntu USB installer drives on Ubuntu Using mkusb, Etcher, Ventoy, MultiBootUSB, UNetbootin, dd, Startup Disk Creator or Disks. Disks, dd and Startup Disk Creator come packaged with Ubuntu. SDC is probably the simplest to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Ubuntu's Built in "Startup Disk Creator" software. It is GUI and easy to use.