# I get a black screen when trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04.2 (dual boot with Windows 10) from grub menu. nomodeset doesn't fix this

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, alienware

After installing Ubuntu from a live USB - I have been unable to boot Ubuntu. When I select Ubuntu from the grub screen, I immediately get a black, empty screen. I am aware of issues caused by Nvidia GPUs (I have an RTX 3070), but none of the proposed solutions that I have come across work.

When I select recovery mode, I see a fast moving column of white text but it suddenly switches back to the black screen again, forcing me to manually power down my laptop.

If anyone has any suggestions that might help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks! I am fairly new to Ubuntu, so I'm sure this is user error. I have already disabled Secure Boot in UEFI. How would I go about installing the correct Nvdia drivers if I can't access Ubuntu? Is there a way to access the terminal without booting in?

Comment: Since the problem is so acute and nomodeset doesn't help it seems like your graphics card might not be to blame and Ubuntu just failed to install correctly. Maybe the iso did not get correctly written to your installation media (I guess you used a USB flash drive to install?) Maybe see [karel's post on that](https://askubuntu.com/a/674454/527764). You can also try running [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to get information on your boot setup in case the problem may be there - you can add the info link to your post. More hardware details may also help.