# Xubuntu 20.04 installation screen never pass the checksum

Tags: xubuntu, unetbootin

Hi it's the first time I try another OS besides of Windows so I've choosed Xubuntu 20.04 which I downloaded from the official page, so I've downloaded Unetbootin and created the boot image in my hdd, everything fine but when I enter in the Install Xubuntu option it load the blue bar and everything says OK, after that the next thing happens is the checksum part saying not such file loaded with every file, this is what I see:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with `created the boot image in my hdd`? Make the boot image on an usb-stick and boot that, then install ... ;)
If you need some help there are official tutorials: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Unetbootin allows you to use your hdd to boot an image, I don't have a USB stick

Comment: Seems like you did not create your "boot partition" properly: It's NTFS and missing files. Go back and try again.

Comment: I see errors detected in media validation so I'd not expect it to boot, and if it did, I'd not trust it for install anyway. I'd return to the prior step (validation of ISO or https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) to ensure your ISO was valid, then re-write to media gain (it's the write to media that gives me the most troubles; about 3-8% of writes seem to fail which for me is a lot of failures a year).   If you can be bothered, you could optionally use another box to verify media but expect the same.

Comment: the same iso works in a VM so I know the iso is fine

Comment: Your logic is faulty or incomplete... unless the VM was on the same identical hardware and the virtualization software made no changes to how hardware is detected.. which is extremely unlikely (rules out vmware, vbox etc...)  but I did say the write to media is the most likely flaw in my experience...   (did it verify on VM & you checked there were no *squashfs* errors etc.. you didn't say)

Comment: yes I know you can write an image-file to any storage device.... yet I had the feeling you might have had some misconceptions ... anyway here is what I would do in absens of an an usb-drive:   create TWO partitions via disk-manager (or what ever it is called in windows), one 4GB and the other atleast 10GB; the first is for the install image, the second is where you later install xubuntu on. Leave both unformatted. then create a new image to the the first partition, as previously something went wrong as both user535733 and guiverc pointed out ... good luck

Comment: Is not possible, Unetbootin doesn't allows me to choose a partition, it's installed in the C:/ root

Comment: Also I've managed to "fix" the checksum error by renaming the "boot" folder, apparently is a Windows protected folder and changed the dir name in the Unetbootin list, now everything seems to be ok but now is stucked at "Scanning disk for index files"

Comment: a friend lent me a USB stick and now I'm running Xubuntu 20.04, Unetbootin HDD installation is broken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)