# Download in Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Running Windows 7.  Want to dual boot at first as I am new to Linux.  Do I download to my C drive or a USB flash drive?  When I started to download Unbuntu to my C drive, I selected the file to download to.  When I looked for it in windows explorer, the name had "trip advisor" in it.  So, I cancelled it, then deleted it.  What is the flash drive for if I am downloading to the C drive in windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu is not an *application* that runs under Windows. Ubuntu is a completely separate Operating System, independent of and equal to Windows. But it's not a Windows clone -- Ubuntu is quite different in many ways.

Windows cannot be running when you install Ubuntu, therefore you use the bootable installer on the flash drive.

Step 1: You download the Ubuntu Installer image (https://ubuntu.com/download)
Step 2: You *create* the Ubuntu Installer from the image (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
Step 3: You boot the Ubuntu Installer to actually install Ubuntu on your hard drive (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)
Step 4: You boot into your new Ubuntu system

Follow the complete process properly -- don't take shortcuts.
Shortcut = Failure.

Comment: So there are two downloads I need, right?  Ubuntu 20.04 and an ubuntu installer, yes?  And, where do I download these files, to a flash drive or to a windows file?  And, what is the ubuntu installer image?

Comment: Added links to the appropriate websites and tutorials, Take a deep breath. Go step by step. You need one download not two (Step 1). You download it to a Windows file (NOT onto the flash drive yet). The Ubuntu Installer image is exactly what it says -- it's the file containing the Ubuntu installer. Just like painting a house -- you need all the tools in place, and to use them in the proper sequence. You can't just dump a can of paint on the ground and expect the house to change color.

Comment: @Janet Windows 10 does have Ubuntu in the Microsoft store after you have enabled WSL but right now this is supported only for command line utilities and a desktop experience is currently not officially supported. It's not a very good idea to continue using Windows 7 in any capacity where it is ever connected to the internet. Use of Windows 7 online is a huge flashing target as there are many known vulnerabilities that will never be patched.