# Problems installing Ubuntu stdin: Invalid argument

Tags: boot, system-installation

If I try to install ubuntu on my desktop pc, i get the following error during the boot process. The problem occours with Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 21.10. The boot medium is a DVD. The downloaded images were ok:

[First error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKUIx.jpg)

After the first error, it shows the ubuntu boot screen, but fails a little bit later with the following error:

> stdin: Invalid argument
> /init: line 49: can't open /dev/sda: no medium found

[Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFQjj.jpg)

I use the following Hardware:

- **Mainboard**: gigabyte x299 Designare EX (latest BIOS)
- **CPU**: Intel Core i7-7800X
- **Graphic**: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710

Comment: *The boot medium is a CD*... Are you sure it isn't a DVD? The Ubuntu ISO doesn't fit a CD since many releases and many years ago. And why aren't you using USB like everybody else?

Comment: Yes it's a DVD.

Comment: So, yeah... As commented before, use USB, reusable and much faster. And regardless of the medium the downloaded ISO should be checked.

Comment: Is `/dav/sda` a typo or did it actually say that? Because it should be `/dev/sda`.

Comment: It was a typo. I edited the post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible to install Ubuntu 20.04. without error using an USB device instead of a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was related to the fact that I was using a USB 3 port. I was able to install it using a USB 2 port.