# Need help with installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I need help removing windows 10 and installing ubuntu. I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.3 to a USB drive. I  have disabled secure boot. Do I need to disable bitlocker? It seems to be preventing me from installing ubuntu. Is there anything else I need to uninstall/install?

Bitlocker recovery was preventing me from doing anything on the computer. It needed a recovery key. Ok so I I found my recovery key, computer is back to normal Windows OS. Hopefully next attempt at Ubuntu installation goes better. My computer is a...

Windows 10 OS
HP Laptop
11th Gen Intel(R) core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz 2.42 GHz
8.00GB RAM
64-bit

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "preventing me from installing" ... are you able to boot from the USB drive you created?  Or are you getting an error during the install process?

Comment: Are you able to boot from the USB stick? Can you describe the issue that you're having with a bit more detail? Perhaps as a step-by-step? This will make it easier to understand what sort of challenge you may be facing.

Comment: Thank you for comments they were helpful in helping me think through what I needed to do. I did figure out how to create bootable USB drive. I also bought an ebook on learning linux OS from manning.com reading this and doing the activities each day. I've got this! Thanks again and Happy New Year!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)