# Sabotaged by X New Star Lite laptop running Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I have a Star Lite laptop that was purchased with Ubuntu as the operating system.

It was put into the EFI Shell version 2.70 [5.13]

```
Current running mode 1.1.2
Device mapping table
fso :HardDisk-Alias hd12a65535a1 blk0
     PciRoot (0x0)/Pci(Ox12,0x0/Sata(0x0,0x0,0xFFF,0X0)/HD(1,GPT,E8B712B6-A82C-4388-A5AF- 
     E0F4A3BD966B,0x800,0x800,0x100000)
blk0 :HardDisk - Alias hd12a65535a1 fso
blk1 :HardDisk - Alias (null)
blk2 :BlockDevice - Alias (null)

Press ESC in 1 second to skip startup. , any other key to continue.
Shell>_
```

Nothing happens when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or any other key; it is frozen. So I was wondering if I download ubuntu and reinstall it will that fix the problem? I am not worried about saving any files.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare an Ubuntu 22.04 live USB by following the instructions in [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/a/674454/), and boot from it. Select the *Try Ubuntu* option to start an Ubuntu 22.04 live session. If the Ubuntu live session runs successfully click the Install Ubuntu 22.04
LTS icon on the desktop to start the Ubuntu 22.04 installer. From the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer select the *Erase disk and install Ubuntu* option.

[image]