# MSI GT77 (128G memory) can not install ubuntu 22.04(20.04)

Tags: boot, system-installation

MSI GT77 (128G memory) can not install ubuntu 22.04(20.04) grub return "out of memory"

I have searched this issue and tried many things i have found but haven't found a solution. I was hoping someone could help.

The same way I have installed it many times before:

1. use ventoy to make a boot usb disk
2. Allocate hard disk space to ubuntu in Win11
3. Close fastboot, safe boot
4. choose try install ubuntu
5. appear "out of memory"

Never had a similar problem before.

The difference this time is that I tried to do this on my new MSI GT77 (128G meory) laptop.

PS, I found out that grub returns "out of memory" when executing the command linux (hdX,gptX).

Comment: The question is totally unclear. Please explain what steps you take and what exact output you get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But I have followed the above steps many times to completion.
I have installed ubuntu many times before without this problem.
I suspect that my laptop's BIOS is too new.
Has anyone successfully installed ubuntu on an MSI GT77?

Comment: I finally solved the problem myself. In addition to Safe Boot and Fast Boot, GT77 has a Quiet Boot in the hidden Advanced BOIS settings. Press ctrl+shift on the right, alt+F2 on the left to turn on the advanced settings. Turn off this option and you can install the system normally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem myself. In addition to Safe Boot and Fast Boot, GT77 has a Quiet Boot in the hidden Advanced BOIS settings. Press ctrl+shift on the right, alt+F2 on the left to turn on the advanced settings. Turn off this option and you can install the system normally!

Comment: didn't helped for me actually, disabled both secure boot, fast boot, and quiet boot.. anything else you did?

Comment: I also used Rufus to replace ventoy, but neither of them worked until "Quiet Boot" was turned off

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem. I bough a new MSI laptop and installed 64GB of ram and I got "out of memory" when I selected the first item on the ubuntu boot menu.

I tried countless combinations of failures including what was describe in other posts on this site and other sites.

I determined that the problem is related to the boot program being a 32 bit program which allows a total of 4GB of memory space for the boot program to use. My laptop as an i7-12800hx processor with integrated graphics and an nvidia-3070ti.

I tried the same install usb drive on a PC with no integrated video card on the CPU and it worked fine. The PC it work on had a thread-ripper CPU with no integrated graphics and a geforce GTX 1080 pci-express graphics card.

To get the laptop to boot and install ubuntu 22.04.1, I had to go into my bios (right ctrl-shift, left alt-f2 to get to the advanced bios) and switch primary display to the PEG (PCI Express Graphics (nvidia rtx 3070ti)) and disable anything to do with the intel integrated graphics on the chip. Then I had to hook up a monitor with a lower resolution (1680x1050 ) (through a thunderbolt docking station) to get it to work. I tried with a 4K monitor but it did not sync up properly. Doing all of this prevented the mapping of shared memory to the graphics controller into the lower 4GB of ram.

After I did all of that, the installation worked. I could boot from the USB boot menu and install ubuntu 22.04. After the installation was complete, I had to switch my graphics back to normal in the bios.

This fix worked great for me. The installation was basically flawless and it did not involve creating new ramfs file systems or modifying grub. No software changes at all. It was simply disabling the integrated graphics in my bios for the install.

By the way, after about 30 failed attempts, I went and installed fedora 36 to see if it was related to ubuntu. Fedora installed fine the first time. I just could not get the drivers that I needed to use nvenc in ffmpeg and still have the system boot after loading drivers. It failed so I went back to trying to find the solution using ubuntu.

Also, I did leave the secure-boot disabled from one of my many earlier attempts. You will probably need to disable secure-boot functionality in your bios also. (See other posts on this topic for that)

I hope this post helps you solve your installation problem.

dave hansen

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description, the problem I ran into before had little to do with the graphics card. Also, I ended up installing garuda linux, which worked well for the new hardware drivers