# Can not boot ubuntu from DVD

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso on a Dell Inspiron 3268 running Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon. The download passed the sha sum test. I then burnt it to a DVD and booted it from my DVD drive. The Ubuntu logo appeared on the screen with a revolving icon but despite my computer making a lot of noise for over 10 minutes it did not load Ubuntu. The following appeared on the screen:

[image]

I tried again but with safe graphics mode but with a similar result. I also tried replacing quiet splash with nomodeset and again the computer made a lot of noise for a long time but Ubuntu did not load. Initially a lot of green OKs were racing up my screen but eventually they slowed down and got replaced with orange Failures and finally the flow of text stopped. At that point my screen looked like this:

[image]

I would like to get Ubuntu working using a live DVD. If anyone can suggest how I could do this I would be very grateful.

Edit: I have been asked whether my question is answered at [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso). The answers there suggest lots of alternative approaches for different situations but I am not currently wanting to randomly try different approaches. I want to know why the approach I have taken is not working. If someone can shed light on that I think it would be very useful to me and hopefully others.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO before burning to DVD?  Normally this indicates something is wrong or incomplete with the ISO you wrote to disk

Comment: I did verify the integrity of the file with sha sum test. I have not authenticated the ISO with GPG as I do not understand how to and the instructions at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview did not make enough sense to me to be able to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: No it does not. I was asking about a DVD not a USB drive. Also, I was interested to know how the (valid?) approach which I took did not work as I would like to get that approach working. It seems to me that the response to the fact that installing OS systems is very error prone is to just try more and more ways of doing it. Surely, it would be far more satisfactory to have one way which was simple, cheap and reliable. Its enough to make me head back to MS Windows! Aghghhg!!!