# Ubuntu 22.04 desktop install fails to complete

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, versions

I downloaded the 22.04 AMD 64bit iso file and it matched the expected shasum value, passing the validation. I burned a dvd disk and attempted the installation.

It failed to complete the install with a message stating that it couldn't open the installer.  I thought maybe something was wrong with the disk so I made a usb boot stick and attempted the install using this method and it also failed to load the installer.

I again tried to create a dvd from the iso using a new DVD disk and again the third attempt failed.  I have a ACER desktop AMD 64bit machine and my current Ubuntu version is 21.10.  Has anyone else run into this problem?

Also I noticed that the install directory on the usb stick is empty, not sure if that is on purpose or if that could be part of the problem.

Comment: What flashing software are you using?

Comment: I suggest that you start over and follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you still have problems, please reference the tutorial so we know exactly where you were derailed. If you are getting error messages, please copy/paste or type the entire error message in your question. Error messages tell you what's wrong - so if you aren't sure what it means, we need to see it in order to tell you what it means.

Comment: I am using the startup disk creator program that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: The exact  error message reads :
Failed to start Ubuntu live CD installer.  Service.y..el crash signatures...

Comment: Startup Disk Creator may have problems with ISOs other than the one for the running system, so maybe try mkusb or even just use dd to write the ISO to a USB.  Lots of instructions here for either of those actions.

Comment: If you have dualboot with Windows, try to use Rufus app for creation of USB bootable stick (app can be run only on Windows) http://rufus.ie

Comment: Try Rufus(Available only on windows). If you have UEFI system, choose GPT and then create a bootable USB and do a reinstall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: Well, patience is the word for the day.  I went back and tried the usb startup stick one more time.  I put it in and let it run and of course it came up with the black screen for more than 20 minutes.  I just walked away and watched 60 minutes.  I came back after the show finished and amazingly the install screen had come up.  So I ran the install program and it worked.  It just takes FOREVER for the program to start. When the screen is black for more that 20 minutes you begin to think it is never going to come back but it did in this case.  The CD install definitely didn't work.