# Boot failure after installing KDE-standard

Tags: boot, 22.04, kde

I successfully installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS on a HP ENVYx360 laptop, using a bootable USB I created with Rufus.

After updating the system, I then installed the KDE-standard metapackage, to evaluate it. It installed ok, but when I restarted, it never worked again. It fails to boot in normal mode.
In safe mode I tried a few things (dpkg fails, fsck fails, updated grub) but it didnt solve it.
The crazier thing is that when I tried the same bootable USB medium in order to reinstall, that fails too!

During the boot/checks several services (snapd.service, modem manager, hostname service, etc) fail to start and the system just perpetually reattempts to restart them..

Any ideas?

[Errors when i try to reinstall from the USB stick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdonD.jpg)

Comment: @Nmath this drives me crazy. I used the USB to install successfully. How could it get corrupted after 30 minutes?

Comment: I just posted a picture of the errors that I get (and the point where it gets stuck) when I try to reinstall using the USB.

Comment: After powing up, i get the grub options. This happens after I select the try/install option from grub, when it goes into loading. Then I get the errors I posted and it stops there. It never gets into the live session.

Comment: If you;re dual-booting with Windows, be sure Secure Boot is turned off. else weird things like this happen.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know exactly what happened after I installed KDE, I was never able to get access to that installation. My issues with installing and fixing Ubuntu 22.04 seemed to be related other issues/bugs bugs with the specific release. e.g. see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421338/ubuntu-22-04-desktop-install-fails-to-complete)

I tried 10 times to install Ubuntu 22.04 and Kubuntu 22.04 with different installation media and different software. No luck. Never ending screens or boot errors all the time.

Then I tried to install Ubuntu and Kubuntu 22.10 and it worked like a charm.