# Not able to load ubuntu 22.04 via DVD drive

Tags: boot

I am creating bootable DVD disk with Ubuntu 22.04 ,It was not work to load Ubuntu
ended with below error
*Failed  to start modem manager

- failed to start snap daemon
  can any one help here?

Comment: Why not use a thumb-drive?   DVD or *optical media* is not the intended installation media for modern Ubuntu, and some users can suffer from *timeout* issues on optical drives which are interpreted as the error messages you are getting.  If you repeat the process a number of times you'll usually get it working, but booting & installing from hard-drive/ssd/thumb-drive or other *flash* media is the easiest fix.  It was hoped for a better solution for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS media for *optical media*, but it's now been pushed to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS/Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: 1. You might have better luck via DVD with one of the lighter community flavours of Ubuntu: Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu, but agree with @guiverc's description of the problem and solution; 2. Please tell us about your hardware: Brand name and model of the computer and of the graphics card/chip, and tell us how much RAM there is. Knowing more about your computer we have better chances to help get a working Ubuntu or Ubuntu family system, or if the computer is very old, maybe some other Linux distro.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be in the software.  https://youtu.be/5ve6qo5HOxM is not ideal, but, gives a superb start.  The numbers should be identical for any software but their location may be different.  I have tried this on a misinstalled K3B.  I think that upgrading to 22.04 is wrong for this software.