# CD/DVD error when installing Ubuntu: "The system log contains an error"

Tags: dual-boot

> The system log from your installation contains an error. The specific error commonly occurs when there is an issue with the media from which you were installing. This can happen when your media is dirty or damaged or when you've burned the media at a high speed. Please try cleaning the media and or burning new media at a lower speed. In the event that you continue to encounter these errors it may be an issue with your CD/DVD drive.

I tried to install Ubuntu but it is showing this error. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: follow the advise already given ?

Comment: You've provided few specific details; if I see that error message, given I don't use *optical* media it means errors were detected on the installation media (be it HDD/ssd/thumb-drive/CF or *optical*) and I return to re-validate the ISO being validate, and verify the ISO was written correctly to the media (*how this step is done varies on product/release where you gave no details*).  Did you verify ISO & write of ISO to media?  (*using methods appropriate for your unstated product/release*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 1):

The error message really cannot be explained much clearer than it already is. **There is a problem with the installation CD/DVD.** The error provides some common reasons why this may be the case and potential solutions, like cleaning the disk. If cleaning the disk doesn't help, then create new installation media.

I recommend you follow the advice from @guiverc to verify the ISO download.  Here's  [how to verify Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu).

USB installation media is more common, faster, and arguably easier to use than DVD media.  The official tutorial to [install Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) begins with explaining how to create USB installation media.