# Failed handling of the snapd snap

Tags: boot, system-installation, snap

I'm attempting to setup ubuntu on a Dell Precision 690. I flashed an image of ubuntu onto a flash drive and followed the instructions on the site to get it running. I got to the stage where it asked me to restart and remove the flash drive when I ran into this error. I got some text popping up before The ubuntu loading screen appeared but then quickly switched back to a black screen with the error messages as follows:

[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.

[FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.

[FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.

[FAILED] Failed to start Failure handling of the snapd snap.

The last error is what I'm focusing on as it appeared only after the ubuntu loading screen stopped. I've searched the problem elsewhere as well on this site, but it seems to happen in much different scenarios than this. I'm very new to working with computers in this way so please be patient with me if I don't know what something is.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What is the hardware?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)