# New system build, need sanity check on components

Tags: asus, amd-processor

I am going to be building a new system for algorithmic studies.  CPU = AMD Athlon 3000G, M/B = Asus Prime B450M-A, 64 GB RAM.  This will use the on-chip GPU for the display.  I intend to load/install the OS off of a USB storage device (?USB 3.0?).  I am assuming I can do this with Ubuntu.  Am I correct?  What do I need to watch out for?  I've not loaded a Linux operating system before, except for my RaspberryPI that didn't work out for me for the studies I'm running.  OH, my regular PC is Windows 10 and I will be using that to download and install Ubuntu onto the USB drive.

Comment: Before starting read all this info. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: Thank you to all 3

Answer (score 0):

None of the components you have mentioned would have any issue running any Linux variant, you're more likely to have issues with things like wifi adapters, occasionally wired ethernet adapters, and other peripherals.

Your motherboard's UEFI bios would need to be able to boot from a USB device, but that is almost universally supported these days.