# Why has my 32 GB bootable USB stick shrunk to 3.88 MB

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, partitioning, usb, live-usb

I wanted to install Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and created a bootable USB stick using balenaEtcher. I  used a 32 GB SanDisk USB stick for this. After doing this I found that the size was reduced to 3.88 MB and the contents of the USB drive was just a folder named efi, which in turn had a folder named 'boot' with the following files: bootx64.efi, grubx64.efi, mmx64.efi.

I found out that the USB drive had been partitioned and there is 28.38 GB of unallocated space. Can you please let me know if I can use this USB stick to boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: Just try ? looks fine

Comment: You probably wrote the ISO as bootable (and *installable*) media and haven't yet installed it.  If you wrote the ISO to thumb-drive, you boot the thumb-drive & install from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

That happens after burning an OS to your USB drive, after you are finished using it for that purpose, you can reformat it so it goes back to its original state. If by any reason it stays with limited capacity (which has happened to me a couple times) you can solve it by using `Gparted`, `fdisk` or similar software, I used to solve that problem on Windows using `diskpart`.